# What's the Halacha of a wall with a gate?

Tags: halacha, eruv-chatzerot

In many apartment buildings, the parking area (or even living area) is surrounded by a fence with gates, from where cars are able to come in or out.

It looks something like:

[image: fence with gate]

Now, if you'll notice, it's a full gate (so when it's closed, it's fully closed), but when it's open, there's *nothing* on top (so no Tzuras HaPesach).

In short, when a car leaves, the gate is a pirtza, at times by more than 10 amos.

The [Aruch HaShulchan](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A9%D7%A1%D7%92#.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.9E.D7.9F_.D7.A9.D7.A1.D7.92_.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.9C.D7.95) writes (and I don't think anyone argues, it seems to be a clear Gemara) that

> וכל אלו התקונים הם כשאין ברוחב הצד הרביעי הפרוץ יותר מעשר אמות. אבל ביותר מעשר - לא מהני תקונים אלו, בין במבוי בין בחצר, עד שיעשו צורת הפתח כמ"ש בסוף סימן הקודם.

That a Lechi and Koreh only help when the breach is less than 10 Amos, and in this case, only a Tzuras HaPesach can help.

---

Now, if the gate is closed, it should be considered a Mechitza made on Shabbos, which is fine. But when it's open, at first glance one should be forbidden to carry withing the whole parking lot.

Does anyone discuss this case?

Comment: It sounds like the עה״ש does. What are you asking?

Comment: @msh210 because maybe a "pirtza" meant to be opened and closed isn't considered a pirtza?

Comment: dupe https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/71353/759